# Passing data to widget constructor is null

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass an argument through a constructor in Flutter.
When I receive the argument on the new page, it is null.

I've tried changing the

Sending the argument, musicPlayerModel:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: FlatButton(
    child: Text('Settings'),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SettingPage(musicPlayerModel: _musicPlayer,),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Retrieving it, where it is null:

```
class SettingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SettingPage({@required this.musicPlayerModel});

  final MusicPlayerModel musicPlayerModel;
  UserApi _userApi = UserApi();
  UserModel _userModel = UserModel();

  _SettingPageState createState() =>
      _SettingPageState(musicPlayerModel, _userModel, _userApi);
}
```

`_musicPlayer` is instantiated at the beginning of the first page. I also checked that the value is not null with the debugging tool.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  User user;

  _MainPageState(userInfo) {
    this.user = User(userInfo);
    _musicPlayer = MusicPlayerModel(user);
  }
```

I'm probably missing something fundamental in terms of creating a new page?

Comment: can you show where are you setting the musicPlayerModel, maybe it was null when you pressed the button

Comment: in ``_SettingPageState`` try to access the data of  ``SettingPage`` by using ``widget.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME``, I do mean don't pass your ``vars`` down to ``__SettingPageState``

Comment: @Abdulrahman this was a good catch, however musicPlayerModel is still null when SettingPage receives it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the page outside the MaterialPageRoute

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: FlatButton(
    child: Text('Settings'),
    onPressed: () {
    final page = SettingPage(musicPlayerModel: _musicPlayer);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => page,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: I added your first line to the `_MainPageState` but it is unfortunately still null. Also it said that `_musicPlayer` had to be static. Since that model doesn't change, I tried that, but with no success.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't the issue.
The thing here is that for accessing the musicPlayerModel inside the state, you should access like this:  ```widget.musicPlayerModel``` there is no need to pass it to the constructor.